# Laravel: complex query filters inside scope function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a User model and an Availability model:
`User -> hasMany() -> Availabilities`

The `user_availability` table is like

```
id  | user_id |      date 
123 |  12345  |   2024-02-01   
124 |  12345  |   2024-02-02
125 |  12345  |   2024-02-03
126 |  45678  |   2024-02-01 
127 |  45678  |   2024-02-03
```

Now, I want to query the user who is **completely available** during a certain period. For example, for the period of `2024-02-01` to `2024-02-03`, the user `12345` should be returned, whereas the user `45678` should not because this user is not available on 2024-02-02.

In my `UserController.php`, I have

```
 $query->whereHas('availabilities', function ($query) use ($periodStartDate, $periodEndDate) {
     $query->fullyAvailable($periodStartDate, $periodEndDate);
 });
```

And inside the `Availability.php` model class, I tried to write a scope function:

```
public function scopeFullyAvailable($query, $startDate, $endDate)
{
   $query->where() // some additional filters
         ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
                $startDate = Carbon::parse($startDate);
                $endDate = Carbon::parse($endDate);

                for ($date = $startDate; $date->lte($endDate); $date->addDay()) {
                     $query->whereDate('date', $date->toDateString());
                }
            })
}
```

But this function will return both the users because it tries to find if there is any $date that falls in the period and returns as positive. How to modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is very simple, just use whereBetween in the scope and it will filter the availabilities within the specified date range directly, and it will only return users who have availabilities for every day within that range.

The havingRaw will count of unique dates for each user within the range equals the total number of days in the range. If a user is missing any date in the range, the count won't match, and they won't be included.

```
public function scopeFullyAvailable($query, $startDate, $endDate) {
    $totalDays = Carbon::parse($startDate)->diffInDays(Carbon::parse($endDate)) + 1;

    $query->whereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate])
        ->groupBy('user_id')
        ->havingRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT date) = ?', [$totalDays]);
}
```

Comment: It does not seem to work... I can see the `User` 45678 still gets returned...

Comment: ahhh okay, i get it now, please wait while I rewrite this again.